# rails loop take 5 and show next 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, limit, admin, dashboard

Hello i have a loop in my rails project.
i want to display 5 events in the dashboard controller.
is there a way to show the next 5 events?

```
 <% @events.take(5).each do |event| %>
 <tr>
 <td> <%= link_to event.title, event %> </td>
 <td> <%= event.eventdate %> </td>
 <td> <%= event.user_id %> </td>
 <td> <%= event.created_at %> </td>
 <td>  <%= link_to "Aanpassen", edit_event_path(event) %> </td>
 <td>  <%= button_to "X", event , :method => :delete %> </td>
 </tr>
 <% end %>
```

so i want to create a link to te next 5 events.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using loop use `will_pageinate gem`

see gem [will-paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate).

and [railscast for will-paginate](http://railscasts.com/episodes/51-will-paginate)

Comment: looks nice, i give it a shot. u know i the gem is ready for rails 4? (still i want to know how i have to fix it without a gem so more comments are welcome ;))

Comment: @user2746199 yes will_paginate is ready for rails 4, why you want fix it without a gem ? in Rails the rule says that : `You Don’t Have to Reinvent the Wheel`, and i think there is no reason to not using it, i can tell you that the majority (if i don't say all) of projects use an existing gem to paginate their records